# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery' when docker-compose up

Tags: django, python-2.7, redis, docker-compose, celery

I'm trying to start project on Docker. After docker-compose up console gives out:

```
celery_redis_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_redis_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
celery_redis_1  |     sys.exit(main())
celery_redis_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
celery_redis_1  |     _main()
celery_redis_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
celery_redis_1  |     cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
celery_redis_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
celery_redis_1  |     super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
celery_redis_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 273, in execute_from_commandline
celery_redis_1  |     argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
celery_redis_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 479, in setup_app_from_commandline
celery_redis_1  |     self.app = self.find_app(app)
celery_redis_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 501, in find_app
celery_redis_1  |     return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
celery_redis_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 370, in find_app
celery_redis_1  |     found = sym.celery
celery_redis_1  | AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'
```

Does anybody know why the 'celery' attribute cannot be found? Thank you for help.
My operation system is macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

My tasks.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import requests
import json
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from celery import shared_task
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

@shared_task(name='download')
def download(url, email):
...
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - celery_redis
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  celery_redis:
    image: celery_redis
    command: celery worker --app=email_mp3_converter.tasks
    links:
      - redis
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7.10
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE email_mp3_converter.settings
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ADD requirements.txt /email_mp3_converter/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /email_mp3_converter/requirements.txt
ADD . /email_mp3_converter
CMD python /email_mp3_converter/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

My requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.11
requests==2.19.1
youtube_dl==2018.6.19
django-redis==4.9.0
django-registration==2.4.1
djangorestframework==3.8.2
youtube-dl==2018.6.19
celery==4.2.0
django_celery_beat
```

Celery file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'email_mp3_converter.settings')

app = Celery('email_mp3_converter', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this? Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problem.
When I executed

```
    docker-compose run web bash
    # Inside
    cd /code/ && celery -A app worker -l info
```

Than it worked just fine, but not with the docker-compose up

It appears my volume setting was incorrect in the docker-compose.yml file.
I changed it to

```
 command: bash -c "cd /code/ && celery -A app beat -l info"
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
```

and the error is gone. I think the solution to this problem is checking what WORKDIR you're setting in your Dockerfile and what volume you're using in the docker-compose.yml file for celery image. It's hard to give "work in all cases" solution.

Note that you should first check if celery runs at all by logging into docker's shell.

Hope that helps to narrow down the issue.